# how can i understand templateColumns, templateRows, colSpan, RowSpan

Tags: chakra-ui

I'm new to learning chakra UI, and I want to use Grid in order for the Website to be responsive, so I opened the documentation for chakra and found this example:

```
<Grid
  h='200px'
  templateRows='repeat(2, 1fr)'
  templateColumns='repeat(5, 1fr)'
  gap={4}
>
  <GridItem rowSpan={2} colSpan={1} bg='tomato' />
  <GridItem colSpan={2} bg='papayawhip' />
  <GridItem colSpan={2} bg='papayawhip' />
  <GridItem colSpan={4} bg='tomato' />
</Grid>
```

But I did not understand how the following three elements are used:

```
templateColumns
templateRows
colSpan
RowSpan
```

and how can i use "templateColumns='repeat(3, 1fr)'" in Chakra UI"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`template-rows`[Template-Rows](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows) property in CSS is used to set the number of rows and height of the rows in a `grid`

`template-columns`[Template-Columns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns) property in CSS is used to set the number of columns and size of the columns of the `grid`

The `colspan` [Col-Span](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp#:%7E:text=The%20colspan%20attribute%20defines%20the%20number%20of%20columns%20a%20cell%20should%20span.) attribute defines the number of columns a cell should span.

The `rowspan` [Row-Span](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp)attribute in HTML specifies the number of rows a cell should span

`note*:` `rowspan` `colspan` are used as attributes of an `html` `tr` or `td` on a `table`.

`template-columns`& `template-rows` are used as as `css` property on a `grid` no matter what `htmltag` was used

Comment: Ok thanks, Is there any link to understand for those things?

Comment: yes there are i will link them

Comment: i added the links in the answer

Comment: please accept the answer if it helped you by checking the tick-mark